# run cmd command in Qt without display it

Tags: c++, qt

I would like to execute a cmd command and without the console appears in Qt

exemple if i want execute this command after clicked in a button:

```
netsh wlan show profile>ProfileWifi.txt
```

Comment: Just use a QProcess (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html).

Comment: Extra tip: you can read command's output directly without dumping it to file. See `readChannel()` and `read()` in `QProcess` docs